# Display popup or admin-notice after add new categories

Tags: admin, notices

I need to display an admin notice or better a js popup after adding a new category.
In my functions.php I've created 2 functions:

```
add_action('create_category', 'popup_reminder_caller');
function popup_reminder_caller()
{
    add_action('admin_notices','popup_reminder');

}

function popup_reminder(){
   ?>
    <div class="error notice">
        <p><?php __( 'There has been an error. Bummer!' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php    
}
```

but doesn't work. The hook is correctly called (I'm debugging) but the notice won't shows. I did try with `echo` instead of `__` but doesn't work either.